# tricky SQL query

Tags: sql

So I have this table, with 3 columns: ID (unique key), PositionID, and SupervisorID.  PositionID and SupervisorID are both foreign keys to a Positions table.

What I haven't been able to figure out is a decently nice way of getting *inherited* subordinates.  So for example:

---

**ID** **PositionID** **SupervisorID**

```
1     2           1

2     2           3

3     3           4

4     1           5
...
```

how could I select 2,3 and 4 as based on their subordinate position to 1.  The current solution is quite a messy way of doing it, and it seems common enough of a problem that perhaps there is an accepted method.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Recursive Common Table Expressions:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If you have an Microsoft SQL Server 2008 you should look at the [HierarchyId](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677290.aspx) datatype. I think it's exactly what you're looking for. You can do it without this type but then you'll have to listen to the other guys. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
    WITH HierarchyCTE (ID, PositionID, SupervisorID)
    AS
    (
      SELECT ID, PositionID, SupervisorID
        FROM SomeTable
        WHERE ID = 1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT b.ID, b.PositionID, b.SupervisorID
        FROM SomeTable AS b
        INNER JOIN HierarchyCTE AS c ON b.ID = c.PositionID 
    )
    SELECT ID, PositionID, SupervisorID FROM HierarchyCTE
```

or something close to that should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this to a certain depth with standard SQL (and probably any depth with various SQL enhancements) but the SQL statements will be hideous abominations from the depths of Satan's own hellpit.

SQL is a relational algebra, not something to be bent to a procedural model. Seriously, use code for that (even if it's a stored procedure or PL/SQL), it will make your SQL prettier, your DBAs and future maintainers happier and your life longer and more prosperous.

Comment: Yea, intuitively it didn't seem like an unlimited depth could be done with straight SQL.  This is in a stored procedure.  Some other stored procedures dealing with this functionality create temporary tables during the procedure (shriek!).

Comment: You don't need temporary tables. If you have a decent SP implementation, you can code it in any language you like (we use REXX for DB2/z) and store your intermediate information in memory.

Answer (score 0):

I've written queries to do this exact thing and explode Bills of Material. I've used a query in a while loop that selects into a temp table and recursive common table expressions. As far as I know, those are the only way w/o using a recursive function/sproc - which is a no go in a production database (in my view) for a variety of reasons (firstly since sql server is restricted to 16 levels by default). I can post code if requested.